# Android SDK debug info is wrong when I debug with AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, gradle

I am writing a android program.The configuration about it is as follows,
[image]

You can see the api is version 19,however when I debug my program,the debug info (the call stack line information) is like this,

[image]

When I double click the shadow line ,it leads me to the
[image]

It seams right as I configure the Api version,however,the `inflate() 504` is actually about the android sdk version 21.
I don't know why ,and how should I let the debug info is right as I configure？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using an emulator or device with SDK 21 (Lollipop) to run/debug the application. That is why your debug window is showing line numbers for lollipop where your application is running.

Comment: Got, it depends on my device 's sdk version.

Comment: Do you know how can I configure to the build SDK, you know, the build SDK information such as the right line, is valuable.